# hbase NameError: uninitialized constant IS_MOB

Tags: hbase, hfile

I am a user of hbase-0.98.18-hadoop2, when I try to create a table:

```
create 'MOBTable', {NAME => 'columFamily', VERSION => 1, IS_MOB => true, MOB_THRESHOLD => 102400}
```

there is an error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant IS_MOB
```

But I have add the following line to hbase-site.xml:

```
<property>
  <name>hfile.format.version</name>
  <value>3</value>
</property>
```

in order to support Hfile version3.
However the problem still exist.
how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache HBase's MOB feature is not available in your version of `hbase-0.98.18`. It has so far only been added into the 2.0.0 release upstream, via the work done by https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-11339. Apache HBase has yet to make a public release with MOB feature included.

You can perhaps try using CDH included Apache HBase, which has the MOB feature back-ported and supported in it from version CDH 5.4.0 onwards: http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/cdh_ig_hbase_new_features_and_changes.html